# Where to find file from instructions on how to use Tesseract API or is there another way to fix this error?

Tags: java, netbeans, tesseract

I'm just so frustrated. I have this personal project that my dad gave me so I could help out his company in my own way. I'm trying to use the Tesseract API to read words from images. I've never done anything like adding a library or anything technical so I followed these instructions to help me out:

https://tphangout.com/how-to-use-the-tesseract-api-to-perform-ocr-in-your-java-code/

https://dzone.com/articles/reading-text-from-images-using-java-1

I followed these instructions to the letter except for one portion (step 7; they ask to put liblept.dll file; after I extracted Tess4j I couldn't find that specific .dll file.) I keep getting an error.

I've already deleted my Netbeans Project and retried installing and following the same steps. I also even thought possibly it was the image file type so I switched between tiff, png, and jpg. Nothing.

The ImageReader class

```
import java.io.*;
//import java.util.*;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;
public class ImageReader {
    String filePath;
    public ImageReader(String s) {
        filePath = s;
    }

    public String getImageReadings() {
        File imageFile = new File(filePath);
        Tesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            return result;
        } 
        catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return "Error while reading image";
        }
    }  
}
```

I expected it to spit out a Hello when it read the png I created with Hello typed into it. But it just gave me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract3051': Native library (win32-x86-64/libtesseract3051.dll) not found in resource path ([file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/commons-io-2.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/fontbox-2.0.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/ghost4j-1.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/itext-2.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/jai-imageio-core-1.4.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/jbig2-imageio-3.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/jboss-vfs-3.2.12.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/junit-4.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/lept4j-1.6.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/pdfbox-2.0.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/pdfbox-tools-2.0.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/Tess4J/lib/xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/kakas/OneDrive/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PDFSorter/build/classes/])
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:81)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:42)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:379)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:292)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:224)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:208)
    at pdfsorter.ImageReader.getImageReadings(ImageReader.java:25)
    at pdfsorter.PDFSorter.main(PDFSorter.java:19)
```

I'm kinda at a lost for what to do because I've only ever did mini projects like build a Calculator up until now. I think it's the issue with the dll file that I couldn't find but I'm not sure. Also just a recent update, for some reason it gives a different error with a different png from the same location. The second error is below:

```
[main] ERROR net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract - I/O error reading PNG header!
javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error reading PNG header!
javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error reading PNG header!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readHeader(PNGImageReader.java:315)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:654)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1256)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1614)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.readAll(ImageReader.java:1066)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.ImageIOHelper.getIIOImageList(ImageIOHelper.java:395)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:224)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:208)
    at pdfsorter.ImageReader.getImageReadings(ImageReader.java:25)
    at pdfsorter.PDFSorter.main(PDFSorter.java:19)
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Bad PNG signature!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readHeader(PNGImageReader.java:242)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

I'm unsure of how I can post the pngs I used because they are in my local drive but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: start small. Try `BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));`. Is `bim` null?

Comment: No bim isn't null

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I finally figured out. Overall the issue lied within the explanation and instructions I used being too outdated. I fixed it when finding new tutorials.

One of the jar files I had forgotten to add to the library folders in my Netbeans Project were in the Tess4j’s dist folder. From https://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/files (which is where you download everything), you need to download both tess4j and lept4j projects. Then from their dist and lib folders after unzipping the folder, add all jars to your project’s library. Then, open the tess4j and lept4j from your IDE as a project and copy their source packages into your project’s source packages. Lastly, look for the .dll files in Tess4j and Lept4j (for each project there should be 2 .dll that just differ in 32bit vs 64bit) and copy one of each into your project’s source package labeled net.sourceforge.tess4j.